# android.view.ScaleGestureDetector cannot be resolved

Tags: android

I am using GraphView in my android APP and including the package into my project works pretty fine. But, there is something missing because the eclipse isn't resolving android.view.ScaleGestureDetector.

There goes a printscreen http://www.mediafire.com/i/?sc8j7r341u126ak

Comment: try after cleaning your project from project->clean in eclipse  IDE menu

Comment: Hi, i already did that. This package doesn't even appear if i do ctrl+space

Comment: ok then <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="?"/> which sdkversion you are using in manifest bez android.view.ScaleGestureDetector is supported from API level 8

Comment: Hi :) i noticed that, i changed my manifest minimum sdk version to 8 and even 9, cleaned my project, did Fix Project Properties and the package is still unresolved :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry for this late answer, but I just solved this problem on my project.

In fact, the solution was written on a little warning, just below all the errors :
Attribute minSdkVersion (8) is higher than the project target API level (7)

I had to change in Project > Properties > Android and select Google APIs Level 8 instead of Level 7.

A build later, all my errors were gone. Hope this answer will help someone.

Answer (score 0):

[android.view.ScaleGestureDetector](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ScaleGestureDetector.html) supported from **API LEVEL 8**.make sure you are using Sdk version 8 or greater then 8 if not using then set in manifest as:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.mkyong.android"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />
```